# How to show jquery alert on page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am Navigate form one page to another,
when am navigate form one page to another i want to jquery confirmation message with yes and no button,if i hit yes then go navigated page,if hit no then it still on current page.

For this am use jquery alert but alertbox automatically hide after few second.
following is code

```
    var needToConfirm = false;
    var PageLeaveCount = $("#totalCount").val();        
    if (PageLeaveCount > 0) {
        needToConfirm = true;
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

    function confirmExit() {
        if (needToConfirm) 
            swal({
                title: " Are you sure want to navigate?",
                text: "If you navigate out of scrutiny page without completing scrutiny asset on this stage will not move to next stage.",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                cancelButtonText: "No",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false
            },
      function (isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
              return true;
          }
          else {
              return false;
          }
      });



    }
```

Comment: Could you add your code for navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Try by using callback of `submit` event handler and `confirm` -

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  return confirm('Are you sure you want to save this thing into the database?');
})
```